# Twitter Bootstrap 2.x plugin for CakePHP 1.3.x

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-1.3

I can find some Twitter Bootstrap 2.x plugin which contains some helpers for CakePHP 2.x, but I couldn't find for CakePHP 1.3.x.

https://github.com/slywalker/TwitterBootstrap

https://github.com/loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper

Those two plugins are so cool but for only CakePHP 2.x.

Is there a any plugin for CakePHP 1.3.x?

Comment: You don't particularly need a plugin for Bootstrap, it's essentially just CSS/Javascript

Answer (score 3):

No, there wouldn't be. CakePHP 1.3 is old, and Twitter Bootstrap 2.x is new. There's hardly anyone creating new projects with 1.3 anymore, so noone would feel any need to create a plugin for new projects for it.

If you're starting up a new project with Twitter Bootstrap, move to Cake 2.x instead. It's much better and faster.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using CakePHP2.x in my personal projects, but my business clients don't allow me use 2.x in their projects...

Answer (score 1):

There's no plugin, but it's not particularly hard to install on your project. Add the stylesheet to your CSS folder, add JavaScript to js, and the glyphicons to img. Call them from your layout and start updating the CSS classes in all of your views. This manual updating of CSS classes is why there will never be a plugin.

If you want to see a particularly well done Cake 2.x project with Bootstrap integrated, have a look at CakeStrap. You might be able to copy the View folder from that and adapt it to 1.3's naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make bootstrap-styled helpers myself from 2.0 plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I had back port a Twitter Bootstrap helper for Cake 2.0. It isn't a plugin, but a helper, just put it in a file called `app/views/helpers/t_b_s.php`. And in your views, replace all `$this->Form->input()` calls to `$this->TBS->input()`. This method is the only method that I have tested and used in a production app.

This method will create many form controls types, automagically or explicit. The 'type' option can be: text, textarea, textdate (text input with jquery.calendar plugin), checkbox, select, radioGroup (you pass an array with valid options with the 'selectOptions' property). You can use the options 'prepend', 'append', 'ly_w'=>[1,2,3,4] (Layout Width: this add the .spanN class to your control)

Also, by default the 'maxlength' property is set by quering the DB metadata. But if you have the model's $_schema property set, it will use the lengths specified there (you can just put in the property's array only the fields you want an strict maxlenght control).
The Flash and Flashes methods also work and you can use them to replace them in your layouts/elements.

BTW: I'm dying to migrate from 1.3 to 2, but I had troubles with the dbo_firebird datasource. I had started with the driver from github, but I had programmed and patched many things, for example the I'm will ask for some help about that on an appropriate thread.

```
<?php
/**
 * Helper to generate Twitter's Bootstrap UI interface controls and styles. 
 * Based on the code from Joey Trapp
 *
 * @author Lev A Gutierrez
 *
 */

/**
 * Helper that captures the Session flash and renders it in proper html
 * for the twitter bootstrap alert-message styles.
 *
 * @author Joey Trapp
 *
 */
class  TBSHelper extends AppHelper {

    /**
     * Helpers available in this helper
     *
     * @var array
     * @access public
     */
    public $helpers = array("Form", "Html", "Ajax", "Session", 'Number', 'Time', 'Text');


    // Confirm Replacement
    /**
     * Creates an HTML link.
     *
     * If $url starts with "http://" this is treated as an external link. Else,
     * it is treated as a path to controller/action and parsed with the
     * HtmlHelper::url() method.
     *
     * If the $url is empty, $title is used instead.
     *
     * ### Options
     *
     * - `escape` Set to false to disable escaping of title and attributes.
     *
     * @param string $title The content to be wrapped by <a> tags.
     * @param mixed $url Cake-relative URL or array of URL parameters, or external URL (starts with http://)
     * @param array $options Array of HTML attributes.
     * @param string $confirmMessage JavaScript confirmation message.
     * @return string An `<a />` element.
     * @access public
     * @link http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link
     */
        function link($title, $url = null, $options = array(), $confirmMessage = false) {
            $escapeTitle = true;
            if ($url !== null) {
                $url = $this->url($url);
            } else {
                $url = $this->url($title);
                $title = $url;
                $escapeTitle = false;
            }

            if (isset($options['escape'])) {
                $escapeTitle = $options['escape'];
            }

            if ($escapeTitle === true) {
                $title = h($title);
            } elseif (is_string($escapeTitle)) {
                $title = htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES, $escapeTitle);
            }

            if (!empty($options['confirm'])) {
                $confirmMessage = $options['confirm'];
                unset($options['confirm']);
            }
            if ($confirmMessage) {
                $confirmMessage = str_replace("'", "\'", $confirmMessage);
                $confirmMessage = str_replace('"', '\"', $confirmMessage);
                $options['onclick'] = "return bootbox.confirm('{$confirmMessage}');";
            } elseif (isset($options['default']) && $options['default'] == false) {
                if (isset($options['onclick'])) {
                    $options['onclick'] .= ' event.returnValue = false; return false;';
                } else {
                    $options['onclick'] = 'event.returnValue = false; return false;';
                }
                unset($options['default']);
            }
            return sprintf($this->Html->tags['link'], $url, $this->_parseAttributes($options), $title);
        }


    /**
     * Takes an array of options to output markup that works with
     * twitter bootstrap forms.
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function input($field, $options = array()) {

        // Checkout how the input parameters are given
        if (is_array($field)) {
            $options = $field;
            $field = $options['field'];
        } else {
            $options["field"] = $field;
        }

        if (!isset($field)) { return ''; }

        $out = $theGroup = $theHelp = $theLabel = $theControl = $theError = $help_inline = $help_block = $theStyleClass = $theScripts = $thePrependAppendClass = $theSelectOptions = '';

        // Default options, etc...
        if(isset($options['type'])) 
            $theType=$options['type'];

        $defaults = array(
            'help_inline' => '',
            'help_block' => '',
        );

//      $options = array_merge($defaults, $options);

        // Determine both model and field parameters
        $theModel = ucfirst($this->Form->defaultModel);
        $split = explode(".", $options["field"]);
        if($split && sizeof($split)>1) {
            $theModel = ucfirst($split[0]);
            $theField = ucfirst($split[1]);
        }
        else {
            $theField = ucfirst($split[0]);
        }

        $options['field'] = $theModel.(!empty($theModel)?'.':'').$theField;

        // Introspects the Model to get field's info
        if (!isset($this->Form->fieldset[$theModel])) {
            $this->Form->_introspectModel($theModel);
        }

        // Get the field's metadata into the theFieldMeta variable
        if( isset($this->Form->fieldset) &&
            array_key_exists($theModel, $this->Form->fieldset) &&
            array_key_exists('fields', $this->Form->fieldset[$theModel])
            ) {
            $theFieldMeta=$this->Form->fieldset[$theModel]['fields'][strtolower($theField)];
        }

        // If the field's type is text or String,
        // then set the MaxLength option when it is not passed by parameter.
        if(!array_key_exists('maxlength', $options) &&
            isset($theFieldMeta['length']) &&
            isset($theFieldMeta['type']) && 
            ($theFieldMeta['type']=='text' || $theFieldMeta['type']=='string')
        ) {
            $options['maxlength']=$theFieldMeta['length'];
        }

        // Generate a Label for the Control
        if (!isset($options['label']) || $options['label'] === false) {
            $options['label'] = '';
        } else if (!empty($options['label'])) {
            $theLabel = '<label for="'.$theModel.$theField.'" class="control-label">'.$options['label'].'</label>';
        } else {
            if(!isset($options['label']))
                $theLabel = '<label for="'.$theModel.$theField.'" class="control-label">'.$theField.'</label>';
        }
        $options['label']=false;

        // Generate the extra Prepend/Appended content
        if (!empty($options['prepend'])) {
            $thePrepend=$this->Html->tag('span',$options['prepend'], array('class'=>'add-on'));
            $options['prepend']=null;
            $thePrependAppendClass="input-prepend";
        }
        if (!empty($options["append"])) {
            $theAppend=$this->Html->tag("span",$options['append'], array('class'=>'add-on'));
            $options['append']=null;
            $thePrependAppendClass.="input-append";
        }

        // generate the error...
        list($help_inline, $help_block) = $this->_help_markup($options);

        // generate the error message for the input field, if any...
        if ($this->Form->error($field)) {
//          echo WCR.WCR."Error-${field}::".$this->Form->error($field);
            $theError=$this->Form->error($field);
            $help_block = $this->Html->tag(
                "span",
                str_replace(array('<div class="error-message">','</div>'),'',$this->Form->error($field)),
                array("class" => "help-inline")
            );
        }

        // Get the control's layout width and define the control's style class
        if(isset($options['class'])) $theStyleClass=trim($options['class']);
        if(isset($options['ly_w'])) {
            $theStyleClass.=' span'.$options['ly_w'];
            $options['ly_w']=null;
        }
        $options['class']=trim($theStyleClass);

        if(isset($options['type']) && $options['type']=='textdate') {
            $options['type']='text';
            $theScripts.=' $(\'#'.$theModel.'.'.$options['field'].'\').datepicker({ dateFormat: \'yy-mm-dd\'});';
//          $options['dateFormat'] = 'DMY';
        }

        // generate the form's input control (main thing)
            //
        $options['div']=false;

        if(isset($options['type']) && $options['type']=='radiogroup') {
            $theSelectOptions=$options['selectOptions'];
            $options['selectOptions']=null;
            $theControl = $this->Form->radio($field, $theSelectOptions, array('label'=>'','legend'=>'','div'=>false));
        }
        else {
            if(isset($this->data[$theModel][strtolower($theField)]) &&
            !empty($this->data[$theModel][strtolower($theField)]) &&
                is_numeric(trim($this->data[$theModel][strtolower($theField)])) &&
                trim($this->data[$theModel][strtolower($theField)])<>'' &&
                !is_integer(trim($this->data[$theModel][strtolower($theField)]))
                )
            if(isset($options['format']) ) {
                if($options['format']==='currency') {
                    $options['value']=$this->Number->currency(trim($this->data[$theModel][strtolower($theField)]), array('places'=>'2'));
                }
                if($options['format']==='integer') {
                    $options['value']=$this->Number->format(trim($this->data[$theModel][strtolower($theField)]), array('places'=>'0'));                 
                }

            }

            $theControl = $this->Form->input($field, $options);         
        }

        // clean the error message, if any.
        $theControl = str_replace($this->Form->error($field),'',$theControl);

/*
        if(stristr('type="text"',$theControl) ) {
            str_ireplace('type="text"', 'type="text" maxlength="'..'"');
        }
*/      
        // create the prepend-append div
        if(!empty($thePrepend) || !empty($theAppend)) {
            $controlGroup = $this->Html->tag(
                            "div",
                            (!empty($thePrepend)?$thePrepend:'').
                            $theControl.
                            (!empty($theAppend)?$theAppend:''),
                            array("class" => $thePrependAppendClass));
        }
        else {
            $controlGroup = $theControl;
        }

        // control's div
        $controlGroup = $this->Html->tag(
            "div",
            $controlGroup.
            $help_inline.$help_block,
            array("class" => "controls input".(isset($options['multiple'])?' multiple-input':''))
        );

        if(!empty($theScripts)) {
            $theScripts='<script>'.$theScripts.'</script>';
        }

        // final control-group div. Set the field's style here.
        $controlGroup = $this->Html->tag(
            "div",
            $theLabel.$controlGroup.$theScripts,
            array("class" => "control-group".(!empty($theError)?' error':''))
        );

        return $controlGroup."\n";
    }

    /**
     * Takes the options from the input method and returns an array of the
     * inline help and inline block content wrapped in the appropriate markup. 
     * 
     * @param mixed $options 
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function _help_markup($options) {
        $help_markup = array("help_inline" => "", "help_block" => "");
        foreach (array_keys($help_markup) as $help) {
            if (isset($options[$help]) && !empty($options[$help])) {
                $help_class = str_replace("_", "-", $help);
                $help_markup[$help] = $this->Html->tag(
                    "span",
                    $options[$help],
                    array("class" => $help_class)
                ); 
            }
        }
        return array_values($help_markup);
    }

    /**
     * Outputs a list of radio form elements with the proper
     * markup for twitter bootstrap styles 
     * 
     * @param array $options 
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function radio($field, $options = array()) {
        if (is_array($field)) {
            $options["field"] = $field;
        } else {
            $options = $field;
        }
        if (!isset($options["options"]) || !isset($options["field"])) { return ""; }
        $opt = $options["options"];
        $options["options"]=null;
        $inputs = "";
        foreach ($opt as $key => $val) {
            $input = $this->Form->radio(
                $options["field"],
                array($key => $val),
                array("label" => false)
            );
            $id = array();
            preg_match_all("/id=\"[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\"/", $input, $id);
            if (isset($id[0][1]) && !empty($id[0][1])) {
                $id = $id[0][1];
                $id = substr($id, 4);
                $id = substr($id, 0, -1);
                $input = $this->Html->tag("label", $input, array("for" => $id));
            }
            $inputs .= $this->Html->tag("li", $input);
        }
        $options["input"] = $this->Html->tag("ul", $inputs, array("class" => "inputs-list"));
        return $this->input($options);
    }

    /**
     * Wraps the form button method and just applies the Bootstrap classes to the button
     * before passing the options on to the FormHelper button method. 
     * 
     * @param string $value 
     * @param array $options 
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function button($value = "Submit", $options = array()) {
        $options = $this->button_options($options);
        return $this->Form->button($value, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Wraps the html link method and applies the Bootstrap classes to the options array
     * before passing it on to the html link method. 
     * 
     * @param mixed $title 
     * @param mixed $url 
     * @param array $options 
     * @param mixed $confirm 
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function button_link($title, $url, $options = array(), $confirm = false) {
        $options = $this->button_options($options);
        return $this->Html->link($title, $url, $options, $confirm);
    }

    /**
     * Wraps the postLink method to create post links that use the bootstrap button
     * styles. 
     * 
     * @param mixed $title 
     * @param mixed $url 
     * @param array $options 
     * @param mixed $confirm 
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function button_form($title, $url, $options = array(), $confirm = false) {
        $options = $this->button_options($options);
        return $this->Form->postLink($title, $url, $options, $confirm);
    }

    /**
     * Takes the array of options from $this->button or $this->button_link and returns
     * the modified array with the bootstrap classes 
     * 
     * @param mixed $options 
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function button_options($options) {
        $valid_styles = array("danger", "info", "primary", "success");
        $valid_sizes = array("small", "large");
        $style = isset($options["style"]) ? $options["style"] : "";
        $size = isset($options["size"]) ? $options["size"] : "";
        $disabled = isset($options["disabled"]) ? (bool)$options["disabled"] : false;
        $class = "btn";
        if (!empty($style) && in_array($style, $valid_styles)) { $class .= " {$style}"; }
        if (!empty($size) && in_array($size, $valid_sizes)) { $class .= " {$size}"; }
        if ($disabled) { $class .= " disabled"; }
        unset($options["style"]);
        unset($options["size"]);
        unset($options["disabled"]);
        $options["class"] = isset($options["class"]) ? $options["class"] . " " . $class : $class;
        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * Delegates to the HtmlHelper::getCrumbList() method and sets the proper class for the
     * breadcrumbs class. 
     * 
     * @param array $options 
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function breadcrumbs($options = array()) {
        return $this->getCrumbList(array_merge(array("class" => "breadcrumb"), $options));
    }

    /**
     * Delegates to the HtmlHelper::addCrumb() method. 
     * 
     * @param mixed $title 
     * @param mixed $link 
     * @param array $options 
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function add_crumb($title, $url, $options = array()) {
        return $this->Html->addCrumb($title, $url, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Bootstrap label with $messsage and optionally the $type. Any
     * options that could get passed to HtmlHelper::tag can be passed in the
     * third param.
     * 
     * @param string $message 
     * @param string $type 
     * @param array $options
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function label($message = "", $style = "", $options = array()) {
        $class = "label";
        $valid = array("success", "important", "warning", "notice");
        if (!empty($style) && in_array($style, $valid)) {
            $class .= " {$style}";
        }
        if (isset($options["class"]) && !empty($options["class"])) {
            $options["class"] = $class . " " . $options["class"];
        } else {
            $options["class"] = $class;
        }
        return $this->Html->tag("span", $message, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Renders alert markup and takes a style and closable option 
     * 
     * @param mixed $content 
     * @param array $options 
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function alert($content, $options = array()) {
        $close = "";
        if ((isset($options['closable']) && $options['closable']) || !isset($options['closable']) ||true) {
            $close = '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>';
        }
        $style = isset($options["style"]) ? $options["style"] : "flash";
        $types = array("info", "success", "error", "warning");
        if ($style === "flash") {
            $style = "info";
        }
        if (strtolower($style) === "auth") {
            $style = "error";
        }
        if (!in_array($style, array_merge($types, array("auth", "flash")))) {
            $style = "error";
        }
        $class = "alert alert-{$style}";
        return $this->Html->tag(
            'div',
            '<h4 class="alert-heading">'.$style.'!</h4>'.
            "{$close}<p>{$content}</p>",
            array("class" => $class)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Captures the Session flash if it is set and renders it in the proper
     * markup for the twitter bootstrap styles. The default key of "flash",
     * gets translated to the warning styles. Other valid $keys are "info",
     * "success", "error". The $key "auth" with use the error styles because
     * that is when the auth form fails.
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @param $options
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function flash($key = "flash", $options = array()) {
        $content = $this->_flash_content($key);
        if (empty($content)) { return ''; }
        $close = false;
        if ((isset($options['closable']) && $options['closable'])) {
            $close = true;
        }
        return $this->alert($content, array("style" => $key, "closable" => $close));
    }

    /**
     * By default it checks $this->flash() for 5 different keys of valid
     * flash types and returns the string.
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function myflashes($options = array()) {
        if (!isset($options["keys"]) || !$options["keys"]) {
            $options["keys"] = array("info", "success", "error", "warning", "flash");
        }
        if (isset($options["auth"]) && $options["auth"]) {
            $options["keys"][] = "auth";
            unset($options["auth"]);
        }
        $keys = $options["keys"];
        unset($options["keys"]);
        $out = '';
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $thisFlash=$this->_flash_content($key);
            if(!empty($thisFlash)) {
                if($key=='default') {
                    $out.='<div id="flashMessage" class="alert alert-info">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <h4 class="alert-heading">Atencion !</h4>
    <p>'.
    $thisFlash.'
    </p>
</div>';
                }
                else {
                    $out.=$thisFlash;
                }
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }

    /**
     * By default it checks $this->flash() for 5 different keys of valid
     * flash types and returns the string.
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function flashes($options = array()) {
        if (!isset($options["keys"]) || !$options["keys"]) {
            $options["keys"] = array("info", "success", "error", "warning", "flash");
        }
        if (isset($options["auth"]) && $options["auth"]) {
            $options["keys"][] = "auth";
            unset($options["auth"]);
        }
        $keys = $options["keys"];
        unset($options["keys"]);
        $out = '';
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $out .= $this->flash($key, $options);
        }
        return $out;
    }


/**
 * Create a text field with Autocomplete.
 *
 * Creates an autocomplete field with the given ID and options.
 *
 * options['with'] defaults to "Form.Element.serialize('$field')",
 * but can be any valid javascript expression defining the additional fields.
 *
 * @param string $field DOM ID of field to observe
 * @param string $url URL for the autocomplete action
 * @param array $options Ajax options
 * @return string Ajax script
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/view/1370/autoComplete
 */
    function autoComplete($field, $url = "", $options = array()) {
        $out=$this->Ajax->autocomplete($field, $url, $options);
        return $out;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content from SessionHelper::flash() for the passed in
     * $key. 
     * 
     * @param string $key 
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function _flash_content($key = "flash") {
        return $this->Session->flash($key, array("element" => null));
    }

    /**
     * Displays the alert-message.block-messgae div's from the twitter
     * bootstrap.
     *
     * @param string $message
     * @param array $links
     * @param array $options
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function block($message = null, $options = array()) {
        $style = "warning";
        $valid = array("warning", "success", "info", "error");
        if (isset($options["style"]) && in_array($options["style"], $valid)) {
            $style = $options["style"];
        }
        $class = "alert-message block-message {$style}";
        $close = $links = "";
        if (isset($options["closable"]) && $options["closable"]) {
            $close = '<a href="#" class="close">x</a>';
        }
        if (isset($options["links"]) && !empty($options["links"])) {
            $links = $this->Html->tag(
                "div",
                implode("", $options["links"]),
                array("class" => "alert-actions")
            );
        }
        return $this->Html->tag("div", $close.$message.$links, array("class" => $class));
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use cakephp 1.3 with bootstrap 3.0.

```
<style>
.form-control {width:auto}
</div>
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('YourForm',array(
        'inputDefaults'=>array(
        'label' => array(
        'class' => 'col col-md-4 control-label'
    ),
    'div' => 'form-group',
        'wrapInput' => 'col col-md-8',
        'class' => 'form-control'
    ),
    'class'=>'form-horizontal',
    )); ?>

 <div class='col-md-12'>
    //your form control here
</div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('', false)); ?>
```